# Problem with sidenav scroll bar - Angular Material 6

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm relatively new at Angular. I am implementing in my project the example of kenji sidenav-1996 [link here](https://github.com/kenji-1996/material-sidenav-responsive-starter).

Many of the sidebar menu behaviors are what I need, however, I have a problem with the scroll bar when trying it for a mobile environment. When you hide the menu and show it again, the menu scroll bar does not maintain the position in which it is left, but it "reboots" and goes back up. I know it may seem like a small detail, but I firmly believe that the user experience is based on that, on correcting those small details and giving comfort to the user

The following images better describe the problem :)

[Scroll Bar Down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkspZ.png)

[Scroll Bar Hidden](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jf0Sh.png)

[Scroll Bar Upwards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7R01.png)

I have reviewed the documentation of Angular and Angular material, but I have not found a respective solution, or maybe I have not understood it completely well. :(

I have reviewed the documentation of the Angular and Angular material, but I have not found a respective solution, or perhaps I have not understood the documentation well. :(

HTML Component:

```html
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="main-nav mat-elevation-z4">

    <button mat-icon-button (click)="start.toggle()" class="icon-padding">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <button mat-button routerLink="/"><strong>Prueba Menu Sidenav</strong></button>

    <!-- This fills the remaining space of the current row -->
    <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>

    <button mat-icon-button class="icon-padding">
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="true">notifications</mat-icon>
    </button>

</mat-toolbar>

<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">

    <mat-sidenav class="mat-elevation-z10" #start [opened]="open" fixedTopGap="64" [mode]="mode" fixedInViewport="true" style="width:240px;">

        <mat-list dense>
            <ng-container *ngFor="let nav of navList">
                <mat-expansion-panel class="mat-elevation-z0" hideToggle="true" [expanded]="nav.dropDown">
                    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
                        <mat-panel-title>
                            <mat-icon mat-list-icon>{{nav.icon}}</mat-icon>
                            <span class="nav-list-item" style="margin-left: 10px;">{{nav.categoryName}}</span>
                        </mat-panel-title>
                    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
                    <mat-nav-list>
                        <div style="margin-top: -20px;">
                            <ng-container *ngFor="let subCategory of nav.subCategory">
                                <ng-container *ngIf="subCategory.visable"> <!--Sub category list-->
                                    <mat-list-item (click)="mode === 'over'? start.close() : null" routerLinkActive="mat-icon-active" style="margin-left: -70px;margin-right: -24px;">
                                        <a mat-list-item [routerLink]="subCategory.subCategoryLink"  mat-line style="margin-left: 30px;">
                                            <mat-icon class="sidenav-icon" style="margin-left: 18px;">{{subCategory.subCategoryQuery}}</mat-icon>
                                            <span style="margin-left: 3px;">{{subCategory.subCategoryName}}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    </mat-list-item>
                                </ng-container>
                            </ng-container>
                        </div>
                    </mat-nav-list>
                </mat-expansion-panel>
            </ng-container>
        </mat-list>

    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content style="margin-top:64px;">
        <div style="margin: 10px;">
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>
        </div>
        <div style="height: 64px;"></div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>

</mat-sidenav-container>


<mat-menu x-position="before" #menu="matMenu">
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/profile"><mat-icon aria-hidden="true">settings</mat-icon>Settings</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/profile"><mat-icon aria-hidden="true">account_box</mat-icon>Profile</button>
    <button mat-menu-item routerLink="/profile"><mat-icon aria-hidden="true">exit_to_app</mat-icon>Sign out</button>
</mat-menu>
```

Component.ts:

```js
import {Component, NgZone, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-main',
    templateUrl: './main.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./main.component.scss']
})
export class MainComponent implements OnInit {

    // Sidenav responsive
    width;
    height;
    mode = 'side';
    open = 'true';
    title = 'Responsive Sidenav Starter';
    navList: NavList[];

    constructor(public ngZone: NgZone,
                public route: Router, ) {
        this.navList = [
            { categoryName: 'Menu', icon: 'face', dropDown: true,
                subCategory:
                    [
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/principal', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                    ]
            },
            { categoryName: 'Menu', icon: 'face', dropDown: false,
                subCategory:
                    [
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/principal', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                    ]
            },
            { categoryName: 'Menu', icon: 'question_answer', dropDown: false,
                subCategory:
                    [
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                    ]
            },
            { categoryName: 'Menu', icon: 'work', dropDown: false,
                subCategory:
                    [
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                        { subCategoryName: 'Submenu', subCategoryLink: '/link1', visable: true, },
                    ]
            },
        ];
        this.changeMode();
        window.onresize = (e) => {
            ngZone.run(() => {
                this.changeMode();
            });
        };
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    changeMode() {
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        this.height = window.innerHeight;
        if (this.width <= 800) {
            this.mode = 'over';
            this.open = 'false';
        }
        if (this.width > 800) {
            this.mode = 'side';
            this.open = 'true';
        }
    }

}

export class NavList {
    categoryName: string;
    icon: string;
    dropDown: boolean;
    subCategory: NavListItem[];
    constructor(_categoryName: string, _icon: string, _dropDown: boolean, _subCategory: NavListItem[]) {
        this.categoryName = _categoryName;
        this.icon = _icon;
        this.dropDown = _dropDown;
        this.subCategory = _subCategory;
    }
}

export class NavListItem {
    subCategoryName: string;
    subCategoryLink: string;
    subCategoryQuery?: any;
    visable: boolean;
}
```

Component.scss:

```css
// angular material colors
@import '../../../theme';

.sidenav-container {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}



.main-nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%  !important;
    z-index: 5;
}

.icon-padding {
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

.nav-list-exp {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.nav-list-item {
    background-color: #FFF;
    transition: background 0.2s linear;
}
.mat-icon-active mat-icon {
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
    color: mat-color($primary) !important;
}
.nav-category-open {
    transition: color 0.2s linear;
    color: mat-color($primary) !important;
}
.nav-list-item:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#c5c5c5;
}

.nav-list-item-text {
    padding-left: 18px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.nav-list-icon {
    margin-left: 5px;
}


mat-toolbar {
    height:  64px !important;
    min-height: 64px !important;

    mat-toolbar-row {
        height: 64px !important;
    }
}
```

In advance thanks for the help :)